# Passing updated information from PySimpleGUI to an actively running thread

Tags: python, pysimplegui, long-running-processes

I have a long running process that I've been running from the command line.  It runs through the entire stock market trading session.   What I would like to do, is to create a UI using PySimpleGUI that I can use to change some of the controlling parameters of my long running thread, without stopping and restarting that thread.  I've seen examples of updating UI from the thread, but not sending updates to the thread once it's running.  I'll start with the example of an easy PySimpleGUI application for discussion sake.

```
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time


def long_running_task(thread_event, update_event, window):
    while not thread_event.is_set():
        # Perform long-running task
        time.sleep(1)

        # Check for updates from GUI
        if update_event.is_set():
            update_event.clear()
            new_text = window.read(timeout=0)[1]['-INPUT-']
            print(f"Received update from GUI: {new_text}")

    print("Thread exiting")


def main():
    sg.theme('LightGrey1')

    layout = [
        [sg.Button('Start Thread'), sg.Button('Update'), sg.Button('Stop Thread')],
        [sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-')],
        [sg.Output(size=(50, 10))]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Long Running Thread Example', layout)

    thread_event = threading.Event()
    update_event = threading.Event()

    thread = None

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

        if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break

        if event == 'Start Thread':
            if not thread or not thread.is_alive():
                thread_event.clear()
                update_event.clear()
                thread = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task, args=(thread_event, update_event, window))
                thread.start()
                print("Thread started")

        elif event == 'Stop Thread':
            if thread and thread.is_alive():
                thread_event.set()
                thread.join()
                print("Thread stopped")

        elif event == '-INPUT-':
            update_event.set()

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I added an update button, hoping that when I click that, it will send updated information from the input box.  I can't tell if that doesn't anything.

Comment: Wrong event for the Button `Update`, it should be `'Update'`, not `'-INPUT-'`. If you need it work when the content of the Input element changed, add option `enable_events=True` to the Input element.  `new_text = window.read(timeout=0)[1]['-INPUT-']` maybe not good in the subthread, try `new_text = window['-INPUT-'].get()`.

Comment: Thank you @JasonYang, changing 'Update' to '-INPUT-' and new_text = window['-INPUT-'].get() did what I was wanting it to do.  I wasn't sure where to put the enable_events=True.   Was that to enable each char that I typed in the input field to fire off updates in the thread?    Also, how do I mark your response as question answered?

Comment: Add option `enable_events=True` to the Input element, like `sg.InputText(enable_events=True, key='-INPUT-')`, then it will enable each char that you typed in the input field to fire of the event, `'-INPUT-'`. If it is good for you, just click the up-triangle on my comment.